# video.js only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, video.js, alpine.js, astrojs

I'm working on a project that was built using **Astro** website builder and in which I'm **Alpine.js** as well. In this project I have a video in which I'm trying to incorporate **videojs** (the open source HTML5 player framework) but the problem is that this framework's JavaScript only works after I refresh the page.

I've encountered this issue in the past and, since I'm using Alpine, adding `ax-load` always sorted it for me, but not this time.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<video id="how-it-works-video" class="video-js" x-ignore ax-load x-data="VideoJs" x-init="$watch('modalOpen', value => value ? $el.play() : $el.pause())" playsinline>
  <source src={howItWorksVideo} type="video/mp4"/>
  <track label="English" kind="subtitles" src="/global-money-transfers.vtt" srclang="en" default>
</video>
```

**JavaScript (from VideoJs.js file)**

```
import videojs from 'video.js';

export default () => {
    
  return {
    init() {
      videojs('how-it-works-video', { controls:true });
    },
  };
};
```

Any ideia of why this might be happening/how to fix it?

Comment: how do you register that alpine component?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Also, have you tried wrapping the `videojs` callback in a `setTimeout`? I've had issues in the past with Alpine finding elements in the `init` function which were solved by wrapping them in a `setTimeout` without any delay, which forces it to execute on the next thread.